# Xcode UITable Button Targeting Multiple Cells

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitableview

I am creating a UITable , the problem that I am having is that when I click a button inside the cell, to change a label inside the same cell. It targets two cells at the same time.

When loading the cells I use:

```
    cell.AddtoFavorites.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.AddtoFavorites.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddtoFavorites(sender:)) , for: .touchUpInside)
```

then in the AddtoFavorites function:

```
    let tag = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell!
    cell?.ButtonText.text = "test"
```

My problem is that when this code runs in does it for two cells, for say I click the button in cell one, it changes the text(UILABEL) in both cell 1 and in cell 4 ... so its skipping two cells at time. Ive been stuck on this and I really need help. All help is much appreciated thanks!

Comment: do you wish to change all uilabel's or a selected one?? @daniel

Comment: How are you reloading table view in AddtoFavorites function?

Comment: You are probably not maintaining the state of the text. That is to say keeping track of what cells text has been changed and in `cellForRow` you don't seem to be checking the state of the cell and displaying text in accordance with the state(wether it should show test or w.e it was initially). So naturally when cell is re-used, the same text appears again.

Comment: Just the Uilabel of the selected cell,,,,I only reload the cell once, thats at the beginning when I download a text file from my server, but theres no problems their,, I use tableView.reloadData(),,,,,,,yes that would make sense how would I go about painting the state of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in adding the target to the button inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. Set the action from the button to the TableViewController as Touch Up Inside in the storyboard. I also cache the tag value in the TableViewController, reload the whole table and set the text value in cellForRow based on the cached values.

Comment: wait what exactly do you mean, I have my add to target like so : addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddtoFavorites(sender:)) , for: .touchUpInside)       It has the .touchUpInside already

Comment: Since the cell is being re-used, and not setting the original cell?.ButtonText.text = "test"

Comment: Since the cell is being reused, you should have cell?.ButtonText.text = "test" or cell?.ButtonText.text = "original text" in cellForRow and not changing it in AddToFavorites. When you change the cell directly, it will draw it the same way for subsequent cells, until you change cell?.ButtonText.text again.